# Why can IHn' (n' = n' + 0) from induction be used to prove n = n + 0 in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, coq-tactic

In Software Foundations's Logical Foundations, they use the idea of induction to prove things. From stepping through the following proof, it is difficult to see why you can rewrite what you're trying to prove with your original hypothesis. Why can IHn' (n' = n' + 0) from induction be used to prove n = n + 0?

Are they not essentially the same statement?

```
Theorem plus_n_O : ∀ n:nat, n = n + 0.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n' IHn'].
  - (* n = 0 *) reflexivity.
  - (* n = S n' *) simpl. rewrite <- IHn'. reflexivity. Qed.
```

[image: Image of proof in CoqIDE]

Comment: I don't think your inductive hypothesis has the form `n' - n' = 0`. Could you double check?

Comment: Im confused, are you trying to prove zero is the additive identity?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Yes, I am.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I've uploaded a screenshot with CoqIDE

Comment: Well, your code says `Theorem plus_n_O : ∀ n:nat, n = n + 0.`

Comment: @InnovativeInventor your screenshot shows that you are trying to prove `minus_diag`, not `plus_n_0`.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the screenshot (uploaded the wrong one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same statement, but about different numbers: one is about `n'`, the other one is about `n`, which corresponds to `S n'` in the goal. Induction is precisely about showing that something is valid for `S n'` just by knowing that it holds for `n'`.  The fact that they are different numbers is what makes this non-trivial.  For example, it is *not* possible to show that `S n'` is odd assuming that `n'` is odd, even though both statements are "the same".

You asked about the mechanics of rewriting. After simplification, your goal looks like this:

```
n' : nat
IHn' : n' = n' + O
---------------------------------------
S n' = S (n' + O)
```

When you call `rewrite`, you are telling Coq to replace `n' + O` by `n'` in the goal. This leads to the statement `S n' = S n'`, which is a simple equality that can be discharged by the axiom of reflexivity.

**Edit**

Here is another way to think about induction.  Let's forget about the `induction` tactic for a second.  It is possible to prove that `0 = 0 + 0`:

```
Lemma plus_0_0 : 0 = 0 + 0.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

We can prove similar statements about any concrete natural number:

```
Lemma plus_1_0 : 1 = 1 + 0.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma plus_2_0 : 2 = 2 + 0.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

However, we can obtain these proofs differently, making fewer assumptions about the shape of the number we are talking about.  First, we prove the following conditional statement.

```
Lemma plus_Sn_0 : forall n', n' = n' + 0 -> S n' = S n' + 0.
Proof. intros n' Hn'. simpl. rewrite <- Hn'. reflexivity. Qed.
```

This lemma states the inductive step of a proof by induction.  Note that it does not say that `n = n + 0` holds for all natural numbers `n`, but that it holds only for numbers of the form `n = S n'` *provided that* `n' = n' + 0`.  We know that this works for `n' = 0`, because we proved it above.  Combined with `plus_Sn_0`, we have another proof of `1 = 1 + 0`.

```
Lemma plus_1_0' : 1 = 1 + 0.
Proof. apply plus_Sn_0. apply plus_0_0. Qed.
```

Now, we know that the statement holds for `n' = 1`, we can play the same trick for `n = 2`:

```
Lemma plus_2_0' : 2 = 2 + 0.
Proof. apply plus_Sn_0. apply plus_1_0'. Qed.
```

This proof does not use directly the fact that `0 = 0 + 0`.  This is why the fact that we proved the base case is irrelevant *for proving the inductive step*: all we need to know about is the predecessor of the number we are interested in -- in this case, this predecessor being `1`.

Naturally, we could have expanded out the proof of `plus_1_0'` inside the proof of `plus_2_0'`:

```
Lemma plus_2_0'' : 2 = 2 + 0.
Proof. apply plus_Sn_0. apply plus_Sn_0. apply plus_0_0. Qed.
```

More generally, given any natural number constant `n`, we can prove that `n = n + 0` *without induction* by applying `plus_Sn_0` `n` times followed by `plus_0_0`. The principle of mathematical induction extrapolates this intuitive observation for *any* expression `n` denoting a natural number, and not just constants.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that you can't use the statement you are trying to prove to prove your statement (circular reasoning). I do not get how `IHn' : n' = n' + O` is proven true in the theorem.

Comment: It sounds like you are more confused about induction in general than how it works in Coq.  This question might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171942/in-mathematical-induction-how-does-how-does-assuming-pn-differ-from-assumin.

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand the theorem now. The hypothesis is true because there does exist `n' = n' + 0` (it was proven in the first subgoal). The second subgoal proves that it works for anything above zero, completing the proof for all natural numbers. Is my understanding correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @InnovativeInventor That does not quite nail it; the base case is not that relevant for the inductive step. I tried to amend the answer to explain that.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand induction!